# Node.js on Google Compute Engine

Tags: node.js, cloud, google-compute-engine

I have established ssh connection. Following that, I have run my node.js application by node app.js on port 3000. It showed console output app is running http://0.0.0.0:3000 port same as my local environment. But when I opened http://external_ip:3000 it is not loading anything. How do I have to run my node app on ***external ip address***

Answer (score 2):

First of all you must have to reserve a static external IP for your VM. If you want to check whether your project is running or not open this following link.

https://[PROJECT-ID].appspot.com

Here is the guide for assigning a static external IP to a VM.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address

Comment: Thanks @Hayder for the reply! And Yeah, it is working fine on App Engine. Coming to static ip, I have done that. I am using compute engine so that I can modify node_modules standard libraries as per my need. I am a newbie to GCP, so I am not sure how to route external IP to my node application.

Comment: @frank_underwood, could you elaborate more about what do you mean by *routing external IP* to your node application?

Comment: After going through firewall docs of GCP, I did solve my issue with apache2. I don't know why nginx configuration didn't work out for me, but apache2 magically did.